# MacBook Pro 2012 - Lagging and slow boot-up

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware

I've left my Macbook pro to sleep with a lot of programs and memory used (probably lot of swap used as well)

And when I've waken it up, it started to have 60 s lags then 5-10 seconds of responsiveness and again 60s lag (with death beach ball)

When I boot up it takes 30 seconds and around 120 seconds to login. (Earlier it was like 20 s for everything)

The craziest part is that when I turn on the Black magic benchmark test of the hard disk drive - I have Samsung 840 evo with 250GB - it goes without lag... System is not so fast but it goes on without lag.

When o boot to Windows it  lags as well (almost without time for responsiveness)

Is this disk problem ?

The video show it all (skip too the moments when something is changing)

Laging Mac OS X with SSD disk Samsung 840 evo: http://youtu.be/9a7CjKuzzsw

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

Interesting info: I've erased this disk, installed via USB SATA connector the Mac os x 10.9.

Then booted. From USB, NO PROBLEM!

Then mounted it to the SATA connector in the Macbook itself. And the same problem ... Of 5 minutes boot up time and extremely laggy Mac.

Maybe the problem is in the firmware of Mac itself ?

Comment: Have you checked your drive with disk utilities or booting from the recovery partition?

Answer (score 1):

disk seems fine, as your tests indicate.
first, best chance:

have you done a safeboot to clear out some caches and repair the hard drive?
shift key down at boot up.  then when it comes up, do a regular reboot.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Boot up times even slower right now :(

Comment: are you looking at the console to see what errors it might be showing?  launch the applicatin in utilities folder and show All Messages.  Also, can you run activity monitor to show what is your top cpu and how much disk activity is going on?  i'm thinking it's cpu lag, and am wondering what the biggest processes are.

Comment: Its not cpu lag. There is something in with the disk. Ive managed to install plain  Mavericks 10.9 and the same thing happened. It loads in 5 minutes, and its extremely laggy as in thr video.

Comment: Look at the edit

Comment: interesting... are you getting any i/o errors in your console when booting sata?  i just had to replace a sata cable in a macbookpro.  user had tried to upgrade drive and ended up killing cable.  they're about 40-50$ to replace since htey also carry bluetooth and power led i believe.